# Visual Studio equivalent for these G++ flags?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, g++

I am compiling a project that uses CMake which assumes the compiler is G++, but I am actually using Visual Studio 2013. In the `CMakeLists.txt` file, I encountered the line

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
```

I think I ought to replace with something like

```
if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ????")   # what goes here??
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
endif()
```

I am fairly new to the world of Visual Studio, so although I know what the G++ flags mean, I don't know their Visual Studio equivalents. I think:

- `-std=c++11` tells G++ to use C++ 2011, which I think is the default in Visual Studio 2013, so I don't think I need a flag for that.
- `-Wall` seems like it probably corresponds roughly to `/W4`, and `-Wextra` corresponds roughly to `/Wall`? But on VS, `/Wall` encompasses `/W4`, so `/Wall` is enough on its own?
- `-pedantic` checks for strict conformance to C++ standard. No idea what the VS equivalent might be.

Can anyone confirm the right flags to use is Visual Studio?

Comment: Unfortunately, MSVC seems to lack an understanding of system include paths, so enabling `/Wall` will usually spam your build output with hundreds of warnings stdlib/implementation headers, so I usually use `/W4` to stay sane :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 but i don't expect any major differences in these flags:

- C++11 is standard, but you should check the [Support for C++11/14/17](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh567368.aspx)-page just to be sure and maybe upgrade to VS2015-compiler.
- Visual Studio has a "Warning-Level" where you can choose between /W0-/W4 and /Wall. So using Visual Studio itself you cant specify both /W4 and /Wall which leads me to the conclusion that /Wall is sufficient.
- The closest i could find to "pedantic" is something i would translate (sry, german VS here) to "deactivate language-extensions" and is the option /Za

Comment: Note that STL recommends against using `/Za` [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/07/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-1/): `/Za is C1XX’s option to enable extra conformance, but it also enables extra compiler bugs in rarely-used codepaths, so we discourage its use.`

Comment: @melak47 Good warning about `/Za`. In my case, it ended up breaking a Windows SDK header, so definitely a no-go for me.