# MSVC equivalent of gcc/clang's -Wall?

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I often build C (and C++) code,  using GCC (or clang) with the `-Wall` flag turned on. Now I happen to need to make sure a small C project, which builds fine on Linux with this flag, also builds on Windows with MSVC.

However, if I run MSVC with `-Wall`, I get many warnings which I find rather spurious, such as:

- `warning C4255: 'some_func': no function prototype given: converting '()' to '(void)'`
- `warning C4820: 'some_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'some_member'

and so on. Now, I realize I can suppress individual warnings with `#pragma warning(disable:1234)`; but still: What's considered a common, reasonable combination of compiler warning switches for C code with MS Visual C++, which is roughly equivalent to `gcc`/`clang`'s `-Wall` switch?

**Edit:** If I were asking about `-Wall -Wextra`, that would be [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369451/msvc-warning-flags).

Note: I'm using MSVC 2015 in case it matters - but not the IDE, just the compiler.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20369451/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/35398878/995714

Answer (score 3):

Be advised that MSVC is woefully non-compliant for standard C code. As you can see, it generates quite a few useless warnings, and it rarely enforces C99 or C11 provisions.

The typical approach is to define /Wall and to suppress specific warnings in the project's property sheet, so that you don't have to sprinkle `#pragma` directives all over your code. Of course, if you're building from the command line, then you're stuck with using `#pragmas`.

Also, it's very often useful to define `CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to eliminate all of the warnings that favor using MS-approved versions of most of the string functions. This naturally assumes that you're not actually using those versions.

About the `C4255` warning -- this is actually required according to the standard, since empty parameter lists are no longer supported. The point here is to make sure that while you're suppressing all of the fluff, you don't actually suppress something useful.

Comment: Oh, you seem to have just answered part of another question of mine... but - what is a project's "property sheet"? Note that I don't actually use the MSVS IDE.

Comment: @einpoklum: See my edit -> if you're using Visual Studio, you can set the disabled warnings in the project. Otherwise, you have to use the `#pragma` approach.

Comment: @einpoklum if you use MSBuild to compile, a property sheet is an injectable chunk of project file, and you can also set these silencing flags directly into your project file itself. Otherwise, you need to pass them directly to the compiler.